# Segwit has been locked-in since Aug'17, has it been activated? If so, why are the communities not implementing it?

Tags: segregated-witness

Since locked-in Segwit, why most exchanges, wallets & miners are not implementing it. Market complained BTC is slow & costly to transact now. Segwit did improved both, yet acceptance by community is LOW. Why?
BTW, is Segwit developed by Core or 3rd party? If 3rd party, how did Segwit get paid?